# search for files in a folder with drivev3

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, drive

I'm trying to extract some data with the drive v3 API but i'm getting an error on the q parameter

I want to search for the ID __ in the parents collection.

```
 page_token = None

response = service.files().list(q="123456789 in parents", spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)', pageToken=page_token).execute()
for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
    print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
```

can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific error that you encountered?

Comment: The problem was the q parameter as I thought... I was forgetting the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
q="123456789 in parents"
```

#### To :

```
q="'123456789' in parents"
```

#### Note :

- I confirmed that in my environment, an error occurs for the former, and no errors occur for the latter.

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.